# View the source code clicking a button

Tags: php, html

I have a form HTML as this:

```
<Form Name ="form1" Method ="POST" ACTION = "">
Signore/a:
<select name="sig">
<option value="1">Sig.re</option>
<option value="2">Sig.ra</option>
</select><br /><br />
Nome<input type="text" name="nome" maxlength="30" size="30"><br /><br />
arrivo: <br />
Giorno<input type="text" name="giornoa" maxlength="2" size="2">/ Mese
<input type="text" name="mesea" maxlength="1" size="1"><br /><br />
```

On this form(that I don't public all because is too long), I have a lot of PHP code that do a quote on the $_POST variables. The final result is a variable that is a mix of HTML and PHP like this:

```
echo $result="<table style='height: 48px; width: 571px;' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0';>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: center;'>$_POST['x1']</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;'>$_POST['x2']</td>
        <td style='text-align: center;'>$Total</td>
</tr></tbody></table> ";
```

Normally the output interpreted by the browser returns the formatted text. I like add to this form a button that when clicked will return the source code that is `"<html> <body> <table>...... </ table> </ body> </ HTML>"` as in programs that use online when you are writing text and HTML source code is given (for example http://www.quackit.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then use could use a [highlight_file()](http://php.net/highlight_file) or [highlight_string()](http://php.net/highlight_string)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['view_source'])) {
    highlight_file($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // For the entire file
    $code = "Your intended code here";
    highlight_string($code); // For the intended code
}
?><form method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='view_source' value='View Source' />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a tot it works nice!can i add a php button to copy in the clipboard the ouptut?

Comment: I'd use `highlight_file(__FILE__);` instead as it's more common. But this works, too. +1